# Refreshing Spring Cloud Config from filesystem not working once my app is deployed on docker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot application for which I externalized the configuration with Spring Cloud Config so I can modify and refresh its properties on the fly.

Here is my bootstrap.yml :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${appName:tasky}
  profiles:
    include:
    - native
  cloud:
    config:
      failFast: true     
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        prefix: /config
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:config/{profile}
```

Updating then refreshing a property (for eg. `app.api-key`) on my local project works perfectly :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9190/management/refresh

["app.api-key"]
```

I dockerized my app and tried to achieve the same result from my container, so I tried the following :

```
sed -i -e 's/oldvalue/newvalue/g' tasky-prod.properties
```

This correctly changes my file, but when I try to refresh the values in my app (from within the container), my spring boot context is restarted but nothing is picked up from the actuator and the new value is also not used by my app :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9999/management/refresh

[]
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you try refreshing the other service viz. the one running on port 9190? Also check if you've set force-pull: true on the config server.

Comment: I'm not using github but my filesystem (see the `native` profile in my `bootstrap.yml`). Port `9190` is used for my `dev` profile (developping on my machine). Port `9999` is used for my `prod` profile (from within my container). I did what you asked : `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9190: Connection refused`

Comment: Ok. Check if you have the correct active profile (in your case, prod) and verify the URL being called on the config server whenever you're refreshing the context.