# Property Source not located by Config Server (JDBC Backend) even after providing application name and URI in bootstrap.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am setting up a Configuration manager using Spring cloud config, I'm having an issue where the Client is not picking up the property source (Hosted HTTPS Server URI) when I deploy the application to a Docker container on Azure, works when the same code is running on Localhost which picks the same URI, thoughts on how to proceed ?

I have provided all the required parameters including the app name and the SERVER URI along with the active profile (dev) and label (1.0) in the bootstrap.properties, I also tried disabling security by setting management.security.enabled to false thinking it is a Security issue, but nothing seems to locate the property source. (Worst case is the HTTPS server URI seems to be located when the client is running locally), It is only when the code is containerized using Docker and deployed to Azure, it is showing this behavior. Any help greatly appreciated !

P.S - Working on latest snapshots of SpringBoot 2.1.3 and latest snapshot of Spring Cloud starter 2.1.1, No problems with any of the dependencies I have added.

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.apache.commons.version>3.5</org.apache.commons.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.12</lombok.version>
        <apt.version>1.1.3</apt.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
        <log4j-api.version>2.6</log4j-api.version>
    </properties>


      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



bootstrap.properties

spring.cloud.config.uri=example.org
spring.application.name=MyApp
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.profile=dev
spring.cloud.config.label=1.0

application.properties

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Expected when running on Localhost

2019-04-03 14:48:42.499  INFO 50217 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : example.org
2019-04-03 14:48:43.961  INFO 50217 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=MyApp, profiles=[dev], label=1.0, version=null, state=null
2019-04-03 14:48:43.961  INFO 50217 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='MyApp-dev'}]}
2019-04-03 14:48:43.965  INFO 50217 --- [           main] c.s.c.backroom.claims.ClaimsApplication  : The following profiles are active: dev
2019-04-03 14:48:44.985  INFO 50217 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-04-03 14:48:45.135  INFO 50217 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 138ms. Found 17 repository interfaces.
2019-04-03 14:48:45.929  INFO 50217 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=1f523ae6-9bf7-3733-ae13-ea87a67e1564
201

Actual Result when running on Docker container on Azure

2019-04-03T17:35:03.470926214Z 2019-04-03 17:35:03.470  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : example.org

2019-04-03T17:35:09.723760869Z 2019-04-03 17:35:09.723  WARN 8 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment] and content type [text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1]
2019-04-03T17:35:09.752928427Z 2019-04-03 17:35:09.752  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.s.c.backroom.claims.ClaimsApplication  : The following profiles are active: dev

2019-04-03T17:35:19.974721803Z 2019-04-03 17:35:19.971  INFO 8 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

Comment: can you hit the config server directly from a browser? ie: http://example.org/MyApp/dev/1.0?

Comment: Yes,  the same endpoint  "example.org/MyApp/dev/1.0" when hit from the browser gets me the result I intend which is the reason why the client is able to fetch the properties when running locally with the same parameters

Comment: I've got no idea

Comment: Is there any configuration Im missing in my docker compose file which is specific to the location of the cloud config server ? Im seeing other questions similar to this one ? PS- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421946/refreshing-spring-cloud-config-from-filesystem-not-working-once-my-app-is-deploy